# Verb form of "likely"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb meaning "to make likely or probable" or "to make unlikely or improbable"?

I'm more in need of the latter, but I assume that if the former exists, the latter might too.

**Edit:** I'm looking for something that is a less-absolute form of *prevent*. Example:

> The old jacket at least prevented me from catching a cold.

is too absolute. So, instead I'm trying to use a word meaning "to make unlikely or improbable".

> The old jacket at least [———]ed me from catching a cold.

Comment: Are you thinking along the lines of "encourage" or "hasten" or "promote"?

Comment: Not quite. Check the edit? :)

Comment: That example usage raises as many problems as it answers! It's in the past tense, so presumably the information as to whether OP did in fact catch cold or not is available at the later time of writing. If he *didn't*, "prevented" is the word to use. If he *did*, it's hardly worth mentioning the failure to **foo** the cold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near-synonyms of *[preclude](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preclude)*, "remove the possibility of; rule out; prevent or exclude; to make impossible" include *forestall, hinder, obviate*.  *[Hinder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hinder)*, "to make difficult to accomplish; to frustrate, act as obstacle ... to keep back; to delay or impede" in particular might serve your purpose, as might some of its synonyms, "delay, frustrate, hamper, impede, obstruct, prevent, thwart", except that tone of "The old jacket hindered me from catching a cold" is rather odd, as if you wanted to catch a cold.  But "The old jacket at least forestalled my catching a cold" may be ok.  Incidentally, catching a cold has nothing to do with thermal effects, and is entirely due to exposure to people with colds.

Comment: Apparently, the reason we catch more colds when it's, well, cold, is that the virus survives longer on cold surfaces than on warm surfaces.

Comment: @PatrickPerini: Have you tried substituting *preclude* / *hinder* in the OP sentences? You needed a kind of converse of these words, actually.

Answer (score 2):

I think we'd really need more context to find the particular word that would suit OP's needs. There are lots of words that mean *make [something] completely impossible*, but mostly they focus on bringing irresistable pressure to bear on whatever agents might have otherwise caused [something] to happen - eg, *proscribe, rule out, interdict, veto, preclude, prevent, prohibit, forbid, disallow*.

@Alan's *encourage* has the advantage that the opposite ("make less likely") is available through *discourage*. The downside is not everyone would like those words where there's no conscious entity being encouraged or discouraged from causing [something] to happen.

In [some circumstances](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catalyst%20inhibits,catalyst%20promotes&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) I think the best words for *make more/less likely* are **promote** / **inhibit**.

Answer (score 1):

Grammar apart, if you'd like to be understood right, *save* sounds better here.

> The old jacket at least *saved* me from catching a cold.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on remarks above: some researchers feel that, overall, the immune system works more effectively at higher temperatures (to a point) and is suppressed at cooler temperatures.

And as luck would have it, cooler temperatures and persons shedding the common cold virus frequently may be encountered together.

> Wearing the old jacket *deterred* a common cold.